# Using Angular, how can I output a variable to HTML?

Tags: angular, angular5

Using Angular, I'm trying to pass a local variable from constructor the into the HTML.

Here is my TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-random',
  templateUrl: 'random.html'
})
export class RandomPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    var restaurants = [
    'Restaurant1',
    'Restaurant2',
    'Restaurant3'
  ];

    var restaurant = restaurants[Math.floor(Math.random()*restaurants.length)];
    console.log(restaurant);
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    {{restaurant}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

`restaurant` is being logged when the constructor fires. I'm just not sure how to display it in the HTML. What am I missing?

Comment: can you mention the angular version? or is this angular 1?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane This is Angular 5.

Comment: i would recommend adding it as a tag

Comment: does `this.restaurant = ...` instead of `var restaurant` work?  you want the value to be a property of the controller, not just a random variable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bind `var` variable to the html (because it's not a property!). Create a string variable and bind that into the html. The `this` keyword is used to access the property inside the component.

```
export class RandomPage {
  restaurant: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

   var restaurants = [
    'Restaurant1',
    'Restaurant2',
    'Restaurant3'
  ];

  this.restaurant = restaurants[Math.floor(Math.random()*restaurants.length)];
  console.log(this.restaurant);
```

Comment: Minor edits: variables != properties/fields/members.

Answer (score 5):

`restaurant` is defined in the constructor scope, not as an instance variable. As such, Angular has no access to the variable. You need to modify your code to match this general format that defines a public instance variable `bar`, and then assigns a value to it inside of its the `Foo` class constructor.

```
export class Foo() {
     public bar: string;

     constructor() {
         this.bar = 'a string';
     }
}
```

Here's the [TypeScript handbook section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) on variable declarations. It might be worth a read.

Comment: Note that, according to the TypeScript documentation linked, *variables are not members!* Here is the [TypeScript overview of classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html): members = *properties* + methods (+ constructor), but *not* variables (as defined with `var` or `let` or parameters).